# User Search Query to SQL Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there pre-existing libraries that will take a user input and transform it into a SQL `WHERE` clause?

For example given a database that has columns `first_name`, `last_name`, and `address` the user could input something like:

```
John State St
```

and the library would build a query such that it would return rows that match a guy named John that lived on State St (or a guy named State that lived on John St, for that matter).

It could also support things like specifying the column:

```
first_name:John address:State
```

I have some simple code to handle some of these cases already but it's getting a little unwieldily. I would think there are some pre-existing solutions to this problem but I'm having a hard time finding them. Generally, the problem is how to enable the user to easily search a structured database with a single input field.

Comment: For a specific programming language?

Comment: You might give [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI autocomplete could be what you are looking for. the css along with it is also necessary please see this link http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for the .js ans css needed.

```
$( "#myInputBoxId" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

and in search.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$results =array();
$req = "SELECT product_name "
    ."FROM table4 "
    ."WHERE product_name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' LIMIT 5"; 

$query = mysqli_query($con,$req);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
     array_push($results,$row['product_name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

}

Comment: Seems like that is only pushing the problem into search.php...what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In this matter you can break down string as multiple values using string manipulation, and then search for each word in each column using "or" conditions.
additionally you can define index on columns so as to achieve faster search.
You might have tried this technique since you mentioned, but you have to look up each word in each column